# React Native: VirtualizedList only rendering 10 items

Tags: react-native

Why does this VirtualizedList only render the first 10 items when it should be rendering 365? If I pass a `data` variable with more than 10 items it works fine, but fails when I use the `getItem` method.

```
export default class ListTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <VirtualizedList
          initialNumberToRender={20}
          windowSize={21}
          getItemCount={(data) => 365}
          getItem={(data, index) => {
            return { key: index };
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            return item.key;
          }}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            return (
              <View style={{height:50}}>
                <Text>{item.key}</Text>
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to still pass a data property when you give it a getItem. getItem is only an accessor to the data variable you pass. By default, getItem is defined as this:

```
 static defaultProps = {
    disableVirtualization: false,
    getItem: (data: any, index: number) => data[index],
    ...
```

Comment: I don't think I understand. If I don't use the data variable and override getItem(), why would it cause the list to be limited to 10 items?

Comment: @Nwah is correct you must pass a data prop to VirtualizedList component which will be rendered. The reason you are seeing 10 items rendered is because virtualized list will render 10 items in the window by default. Since your render item component doesn't actually access item data but only the key you are still getting a proper render. If you try to access item in the renderItem prop you will get a render error.

Answer (score 7):

`data` needs to be present.

```
class DataSource {
  getElementAtIndex (index) {
    return { key: index }
  }
}

const data = new DataSource()

function getItem (data, index) {
  return data.getElementAtIndex(index)
}

function getItemCount (data) {
  return 1000
}

const ComponentView = (props) => {
  return (
      <VirtualizedList
        data={data}
        style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
        // initialNumToRender={20}
        // maxToRenderPerBatch={}
        // windowSize={21}
        getItemCount={getItemCount}
        getItem={getItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
          return item.key
        }}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return (
            <View style={{height: 50, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
              <Text>{item.key}</Text>
            </View>
          )
        }}
      />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need 20, you can try:

```
initialNumToRender={20}
```

rather than your:

```
initialNumberToRender={20}
```

It appears the API has changed:

[VirtualizedList - React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html)